# 'TypeError: Expected a message Descriptor, got Descriptor' when trying to import keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to import this

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5869267b9269> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
      2 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
      3 from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers
---> 52 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
     53 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
     54 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_function__pb2
     18 from tensorflow.core.framework import versions_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_versions__pb2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
     17 
     18 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
     18 from tensorflow.core.framework import types_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_types__pb2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
     18 from tensorflow.core.framework import types_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_types__pb2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py in <module>
     90 ResourceHandleProto = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('ResourceHandleProto', (_message.Message,), dict(
     91   DESCRIPTOR = _RESOURCEHANDLEPROTO,
---> 92   __module__ = 'tensorflow.core.framework.resource_handle_pb2'
     93   # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tensorflow.ResourceHandleProto)
     94   ))

TypeError: Expected a message Descriptor, got Descriptor
```

I have accidentally no idea why it suddenly did this when it was fine before. I tried the solutions for those who experienced a 'expecting bytes' error to no avail. It also seems that no one had gotten this error before.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Can you give more details? Are you using TensorFlow on GPU? Are you trying to do this in a virtual environment? like Conda? What version of TensorFlow you installed on your system?

Comment: @ARAT 1. Yes, I am using it on GPU. 2. I got the error when using Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda3. 3. I am using version 2.4.1. Thank you!

Comment: Your tensorflow installation seems corrupted. Try uninstalling existing version and installing the new releases [`pip install tf-nightly`](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/). In addition, you might also have to [`pip install protobuf`](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `tensorflow` on M1/M2...you may have installed a package that altered the version of `protobuf` required by `tensorflow-deps`. I recommended reinstalling the recommended package using:

For tensorflow > 2.10:

```bash
pip install protobuf==3.19.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

1. uninstall TensorFlow and reinstall it (`tensorflow==1.0.1` for me)
2. `pip install protobuf==3.6`